# PHP drop down menu script doesn't update database

Tags: php, html

The following script is supposed to update my database, the environment column with the selected value for the drop down menu. Right now, the last host is getting a value of 0. What am I doing wrong? It seems like I am not able to track the hosts and the value that was selected.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$host = $row['host'];
$environment = $row['environment'];

echo "<tr><td>" . $host . "</td>
      <td><select name='id[".$host."]'><option value='Null'>Select any</option>
                              <option value='DEV/QA/TEST'>DEV/QA/TEST</option>
                              <option value='PROD/STAGE'>PROD/STAGE</option>
                              </select></td>
                              <td>" . $environment . "</td></tr>"; }


echo "</tbody></table><input type='submit' value='submit'></form>";

if (gettype($_POST['id'])=="array") {

    foreach($_POST['id'] as $host => $val){

            $id_c = $val;
if ($val != 'Null') {
            $query1 = "UPDATE hosts SET environment = '$val' where host='$host'";

            $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

            if($result1 === false) {

            die(mysql_error());
         }

     echo "Environment for Host " .$host. " is updated. <br>";

}}}
```

Updated with working script.

Comment: First of all, for god sake, stop using mysql_ functions. It's been deprecated years ago. Second, you're applying the update where sql column is equal to the variable $host, but $host is a variable that belongs to the while that is already closed at that point. As you're using a "dead" local variable from a loop, you're bringing only the last result from that query to your loop. In other words, your foreach is always updating the same $host.

Comment: I will move to mysqli or POD. In this case, How can I keep track of the hosts and the value selected to reflect in the update statement?

Comment: If I were you, I would pass the host's ID as an argument inside id.

Instead of the select's name be `id[]`, which is impossible to track its origin, I'd use `id[<?php echo $hostId; ?>]`. So in your foreach you can use this:

`foreach($_POST['id'] as $hostId => $val)`

Comment: I am getting the following error when I edit this line. echo "<tr><td>" . $host . "</td>
          <td><select name='id[<?php echo $host; ?>]'><option value='0'>Select any</option>
                                  <option value='DEV/QA/TEST'>DEV/QA/TEST</option>
                                  <option value='PROD/STAGE'>PROD/STAGE</option>
                                  </select></td>
                                  <td>" . $environment . "</td></tr>"; }

Comment: [Wed Aug 19 10:19:30 2015] [error] [client 10.144.101.66] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 38

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. I'll try to explain what you are currently doing and how you should have code it.

**First mistake:**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<select name="id[]">';
    [...]
}
```

You are creating one `select` by host (that's OK). But once it's created, you can't say which `select` goes for which host. The only way you can tell it is with the order it appears, that's not very reliable.
I'd suggest that you identify your `select` with the host id (or any identifier you have).
Like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<select name="id['.$row['host_id'].']">';
    [...]
}
```

**Second mistake:**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $host = $row['host'];
}
// Here, $host contains the last row

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $val) {
    // UPDATE $host with $val
}
```

What's happening here: you are updating the last host with every select value you passed via the form.

Here is what you should do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<select name="id['.$row['host_id'].']">';
    [...]
}

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $host_id => $val) {
     // UPDATE hosts SET environment = $val WHERE host_id = $host_id
}
```

That way you will be updating each host for with each matching value in `$_POST['id']`.
You can `print_r($_POST)` to understand its structure.

Comment: Can you please edit my original post with what the right way it is to do? The following line starts with an echo " so the " inside is not being appreciated. echo "<tr><td>" . $host . "</td>
          <td><select name=="id['.$row['host_id'].']"><option value='0'>Select any</option>
                                  <option value='DEV/QA/TEST'>DEV/QA/TEST</option>
                                  <option value='PROD/STAGE'>PROD/STAGE</option>
                                  </select></td>
                                  <td>" . $environment . "</td></tr>"; }